# creating a "java swing" area using markup language

Tags: java, swing

```
<JFrame
        title="Xml parser"
        width="500"
        height="300"
        layout="BorderLayout">

    <JPanel
            layout_gravity="north"
            background="black"
            layout="FlowLayout"
            alignment="left">

        <JButton text="File"/>
        <JButton text="Edit"/>
        <JButton text="View"/>
        <JButton text="Navigate"/>
        <JButton text="Code"/>

    </JPanel>

    <JPanel
            layout_gravity="center"
            background="gray"
            layout="GridLayout"
            rows="4"
            cols="2">

        <JLabel text="name : "/>
        <JTextField/>
        <JLabel text="age : "/>
        <JTextField/>
        <JLabel text="height : "/>
        <JTextField/>
        <JLabel text="weight : "/>
        <JTextField/>
    </JPanel>

    <JPanel
            layout_gravity="west"
            background="gray"
            layout="GridLayout"
            rows="3"
            cols="1">

        <JCheckBox
                text="Single"
                selected="true"/>

        <JCheckBox text="Old"/>
        <JCheckBox text="Owner"/>
    </JPanel>
</JFrame>
```

now I have to write a parser, called MML(my markup language), to show this in the java area. Sadly I can't attach the picture, but I hope the result is understandable
I want to use DOM Parser and change the structure, but I do not know how to make such a command recognizable for the system
here is what I have written so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("myfirstXML.xml");
            NodeList framelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("JFrame");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the main problem is not how the system reads the code, but how it will depict the command

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to create a Swing GUI using your markup language.  You'll have to actually create the Swing GUI using the parameters from your markup language.

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, you might consider switching to JavaFX (OpenJFX) instead of Swing, to use [FXML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FXML), an XML-based declarative language for building UIs. See this tutorial by Oracle (but may be a bit outdated, at 4 years old). I don’t use FXML, so I do t know details, but it seems to be supported in the latest OpenJFX 16.

Comment: [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html). Note that FXML uses [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).